# How can I fix this Python script?

Tags: python, cvs2svn

I'm trying to convert a CVS repository to Git using cvs2svn and am following the directions [on this page](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2git.html). I got to step 7 but am getting an error running git-move-refs.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../cvs2svn-trunk/contrib/git-move-refs.py", line 23, in ?
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call
ImportError: No module named subprocess
```

For reference, this is what the script shows:

```
usage = 'USAGE: %prog [options]'

import sys
import optparse
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call
```

I'm not a Python expert but from browsing the web it looks like subprocess is a standard module, right? I'm using a Python installation built from source for version 2.6.3. What am I missing for this script to work?

Comment: `subprocess` was introduced in Python 2.4. How did you compile this Python package?

Comment: Are you *certain* that you're running the 2.6.3 you compiled, and not a much older one that's already installed somewhere else?

Comment: [prompt]$ python --version
Python 2.6.3

Comment: Open the python interpreter and try `import subprocess`

Comment: [prompt] python
Python 2.6.3 (r263:75183, Oct 12 2009, 19:59:05) 
[GCC 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>>

Comment: @balor123: What's the output of `/usr/bin/python --version`?

Comment: It looks like the local build of Python was not successful.

Comment: Doesn't the script have some kind of shebang? (the `#!` line) Most likely it's using `/usr/bin/python` and you have installed yours as `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Comment: Ah good point. That did the trick - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have an old version (pre-2.4) of Python at `/usr/bin/python`, from your distribution, and the Python 2.6 you compiled is somewhere else (like `/usr/local/bin/python`). You have the Python 2.6 executable on your path before `/usr/bin`, so when you execute `python` from the command-line you get Python 2.6.

However, looking at the [`cvs2svn` source code, `git-move-refs.py`](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/source/browse/cvs2svn/trunk/contrib/git-move-refs.py?revision=5382&view=markup)'s [interpreter line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) is hard-coded to

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

instead of `#!/usr/bin/env python`, which means when you run the script it uses the old Python.

As a workaround, run the script by passing it to your Python 2.6 interpreter:

```
user@host$ python /path/to/cvs2svn/contrib/git-move-refs.py
```

Comment: …or replace the shebang in the script. I doubt the script is called directly.

Comment: @MichałGórny: Step 7 in the instructions says to run that script, so the asker probably is calling it directly.